# Trying to get a smoother parallax scroll speed and/or depth perception

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, parallax

I'm working on a site which requires a parallax effect. Nothing to fancy.

What I want to achieve is something [similar to this](http://wearefetch.com/) - middle of the page. Observe the scrolling speed, it's..."buttery smooth". So to speak.

What I have is similar, except the scrolling speed, I can't seem to get it. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnaf3e4f/1/).

CSS:

```
section.module.parallax {
  height: 200px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("http://wearefetch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/3.jpg");
}

.up{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}
.down{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="up"></div>
    <section class="module parallax parallax-1">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>
<div class="down"></div>
```

I tried using the `data-speed` in [another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spg3kk2L/). But it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

The code is exactly the same as the first Fiddle except for some added javascript, and of course the `data-speed`, which is set to 10.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function () {
        var $bgobj = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var yPos = ($(window).scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));
            var coords = '50% ' + yPos + 'px';
            $bgobj.css({
                backgroundPosition: coords
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I'm not a front-end guy so, although, I'm sure this is probably something simple, I can't seem to make it work.

Any nudging in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) you need to also include the jQuery library on jsFiddle ; 2) it's not a good idea set one or multiple handlers to the scroll event: see http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: I had no idea I needed to include jQuery library in the Fiddles. I'll look over what you linked. Live and learn I guess. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to set the background to a different (slower) speed than the scrolling, like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yd457/7/) of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452318/parallax-section-initial-background-position-is-not-consistent-with-when-the-pag)?

Comment: @pce Yes, that was it. I had no idea what to look for to begin with. If you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it, be my guest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Parallax effect visually appears if you set the background to a different (slower) speed than the scrolling.

The vertical Scrollbar as a viewpoint moves up and down, the background image represents a object in the distance and moves more slowly than closer objects like a text above that background.

The [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yd457/7/) of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452318/parallax-section-initial-background-position-is-not-consistent-with-when-the-pag) is a good starting point.

The Fiddle handles scroll events and "parallax" through the setting of the  `backgroundPosition` property of a fixed background image.

Demo Markup (css inline only for example):

```
<div id="parallax" style="background-position: 50% 0;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1400/700');">Text in Front appears closer and moves faster</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
     var $el = $('#parallax');
     // scroll callback            
     $(window).scroll(function () {
        updateBackground($el);
     });
     updateBackground($el);
  });

}(jQuery));

var speed = 0.4;

function updateBackground($el) {

    var diff = $(window).scrollTop() - $el.offset().top;
    var yPos = -(diff * speed);

    var coords = '50% ' + yPos + 'px';

    $el.css({
        backgroundPosition: coords
    });
}
```